# two form elements and then post data to another page in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

```
CHtml::form(); 
      echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'imei', $model->getCategories(),
       array('prompt' => 'Select Employe',
          'submit'=>'/mobitracker/index.php?r=details/pathmap',

            'params'=>array('imei'=>'js: $(this).val()'), 
)); 
CHtml::endForm();
```

When a user selects a item am submitting it to another page and processing there.

but now I need another data also to be sent, i.e date am using DJui datepicker widget

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name' => 'date_from',
    'value' => $fromDateValue,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'size' => '10',         // textField size
        'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
    ),
));
```

So once a user selects a employee and then selects a date I need data to be submitted.

How can I accomplish this using yii?

Thanks in advance.

Note: Am using PHP yii framework

Answer (score 0):

```
<inputid="date_from" type="text" name="date_from" class="hasDatepicker">
```

The widget just simply generates a text box with the given settings including the name. You can totally take the name and process with it as usually by `$_POST`. Of cause you have to put that field into your form

```
...
$model->attributes=$_POST['Employee']; // access your form as you should have to do already
$model->date_from = $_POST['date_from']; // access date value
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but please tell me how can I integrate with the above code I need a form which includes both dropdownlist and datepicker after user selects and picks a date form should be submitted.

Comment: I have already told, you just put your widget code inner CHtml::form(); together with your dropdownlist. The form would be submitted and send to you both of values $_POST['Employee']['imei'] and $_POST['date_from']